# Sharing and updating ReadyAPI test projects with QA team

Tags: git, rest, soap, soapui, ready-api

I have put few test projects together in ReadyAPI by now and I need to share them with the rest of Technology team. I was thinking to share the single xml file with the rest of the team but my concern is when the other testers update the xml file in ReadyAPI and save it, their changes will overwrite what I am doing with the projects.
I have been told if I composite the project and then use Git versioning, everyone can use and update the projects without any effects on other users.
My manager advised we avoid use of Git versioning and find alternative solutions.
I was wondering if anyone has any experience or suggestion that doesn't involve Git versioning?
Thanks,

Comment: Don't listen to you manager, vcs for example git is great tool to keep you history of development and to work on the same code by multiple people. Alternatively you can copy and paste the edited file in multiple folders.............

Comment: "My manager advised we avoid ..." You need to ask your manager what he suggests instead!